# GitLab on Google Cloud Platform VM

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, gitlab

I am trying to run gitlab on Google Cloud Platform. I followed this tutorial: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/google_cloud_platform/index.html but now I am at the point when I cannot push the commit to the remote.

```
git@33.22.33.22: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The SSH key is added to the Google Cloud Platform VM as well as Gitlab account. I believe I have to enable git over ssh somehow but not really sure how these things go with Google Cloud Platform's security.

Comment: have you tried SSH-ing into the machine using gcloud so that it can add the instance to your list of known hosts? 
`gcloud compute --project "project-name" ssh --zone "europe-west2-c" "instance-name"`

Comment: Added my key manually in VM management and SSH under my username worked. The command you mentioned worked too, I think there has to be some way to add `git` user too. Not really sure how this works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was somewhere else.

I recently changed the IP address of the VM (to have a static one). Unfortunately, I forgot to change the IP in GitLab settings so the clone links are still pointing to the old one. Hence the `Could not read from remote repository`.